# Hybris include datamodel to HMC

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to display my datamodel (with some 1-n relations) to HMC but not tree element for my project is displayed. I have follower all steps from the tutorial but it doesn't work...

I have included HMC both in the xml and also in the build path. the only difference bewetten the cuppy tutorial (cuppytrailhmc) and my project is that the cuppytrailhmc extends cuppy (my project does not extend another project)

whan am I doing wrong, or otherwise: what do I have to do to display my datamodel project in HMC (I don't have a project for datamodel and another project for hmc - so both of them are one project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the appropriate directives to extensioninfo.xml:

`<requires-extension name="hmc"/>`

`<hmcmodule extensionclassname="..."/>`

The the hmc.xml file under hmc/resources will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes to hmc.xml in your extension.Add new  , etc element .You can refer to any existing hmc.xml .Then you have to made changes to your extensionsinfo.xml and add an hmcmodule.

Checkout [hybrishub](http://www.hybrishub.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new itemType in your [Extension]-items.xml  in the core

```
    <itemtype code="ProductList" extends="GenericItem" jaloclass="fr.portailProduit.core.jalo.ProductList" autocreate="true"
        generate="true">
        <deployment table="ProductList" typecode="8011" />
             <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="firstName" type="java.lang.String">
                <modifiers write="true" read="true" optional="true" />
                <persistence type="property" />
            </attribute>

    </itemtype>
```

The run ant clean all ant update your system